# Angular 2 SPA template - simulate delay/lazy load

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm building a proof of concept using this git repo: https://github.com/rahil471/single-page-application-angular2

I've got a shared container component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

And two (mostly) identical subcomponents:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    template: `<h1>{{welcome}}</h1>`
})
export class HomeComponent {
    welcome : string;
    constructor(){
        this.welcome = "Welcome to home page"
    };
};
```

And the app template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- routing here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to find a way to simulate these subcomponents being slow to load. I tried putting a `setTimeout()` inside the component constructor, but that just slowed reloading of the actual container. How can I simulate these template subcomponents loading slowly?

Comment: These are route resolvers that should be delayed, not component constructors. You can make their templates external and throttle the connection with dev tools.

Comment: I'd like to be able to do it without relying on browser dev tools if possible? I'm ok with making the routes external, but I still need to find a way to properly delay them then.

Comment: [Route resolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html) should return a promise or an observable, this has to be as easy as that.

Comment: Probably is easy, but alas, my attempts at fighting with the Angular2 docs on returning a simple mock promise (see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#) has been met with dependency hell :|